# Netherlands: How can I get my kid enrolled in a reasonable international school in Amsterdam

Tags: immigration, netherlands

I recently got an offer (5000 Euros per month after taxes) from one of the organization from Netherlands and planning to move to Netherlands with a family of 3 including 3.6 years old kid, I've already gone through [Numbeo](https://www.numbeo.com/cost-of-living/country_result.jsp?country=Netherlands) and found most of the information required except getting my kid enrolled into International school, after googling around I found that International school charges way high than Public schools (which is almost free) it's like 6000-15000 Euro/year.

Are there any cheaper international schools, if yes, how can i get my Kid enrolled into one, also, do an individual get some tax exemption on school fee,  any information will be a great help to me.

Comment: The question in your text does not match the title question - please [edit] so that people know what to answer.

Comment: And asking for specific international schools may not be on topic here. It is not even answerable right now because you do not mention a city. A better question might be *How do I find an international school other than just googling?*

Comment: This entire question (neither the one in the title, or the one in the text) is off-topic, as it's not specifically about expats

Comment: You might consider asking "If I move to the Netherlands and pay €6000 to €15000 per year for an international school for my kid, is that tax deductible?"

Comment: What language(s) does your child currently speak?

Comment: Many people putting their children at international schools would receive subsidies from their employer (international organisations...)

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan he speak my native language which is Hindi.

Comment: @Relaxed thanks for the heads up, will ask my employer for same

Comment: @Apollo I should add that most local employers typically do not offer that. What I meant is that these schools exist for a very specific market. If you work, say, for a university or the local subsidiary of a large company (i.e. not as an executive sent abroad by your employer), it might simply not be completely reasonable to expect your children to go to an internation school.

Comment: @Relaxed will confirm same from my employer.

Answer (score 2):

The Netherlands has an excellent public school system, and almost everyone completes school speaking fluent English (which is what I presume you want from an International School).  If you put your child in public school now, they will integrate with no trouble at all, and they will be completely bilingual (trilingual† if mother and father consistently use different languages).

A Spanish colleague has just started his children at school here in Switzerland.  The nine year old and the seven year old are finding it a challenge; the four year old in Kindergarten had a great first day, made lots of friends, and made absolutely no comment about the fact that everyone else was speaking a different language!

† A friend has friends who are Walloon (French speaking Belgian) and Hungarian.  The childminder was Flemish (Dutch speaking Belgian).  The child was fluent in all three.  What they didn't know was that the child was *also* fluent in English (what language do you think the parents used to each other?).

Comment: A major reason to enroll in international schools is to follow a consistent curriculum while moving across countries (you can find e.g. British or French schools in many places) and easier access to higher education in that country.

Comment: @Relaxed True - but that really ought not to be a concern until secondary school.

Comment: It depends, going to a specific primary school might make access to a given secondary school easier, many of these schools have waiting lists. Some people also feel teaching quality is better or an international school will help their children socialise with the “right” people. Some international schools don't teach primarily in English. What I am saying is that there is no reason to assume people send their children to an international school just to ensure they speak English.

Answer (score 0):

5000€ after taxes is a great salary in all European countries (might be a bit short for Switzerland or Norway tho).

About school I don't have any answer to this question but if you're considering moving long term to netherland you may want your kid to be in an international school for 1-2 year, then he should be able to get some dutch basic for classic public school.